# Jetpack compose: Nested scroll with LazyColumn issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I have a requirement to display a LazyVerticalGrid,LazyRow and a Label in a single screen.

I tried to place LazyVerticalGrid ,LazyRow and Label in LazyColumn.
The app crashes with infinite height issue for LazyVerticalGrid.
So, I set the height to 400.dp for LazyVerticalGrid. Now the entire screen is scrolled as whole and also individual items are also scrolled.

Is there a better approach to solve this issue with setting explicit height.

```
     @Composable
       fun Category() {
        Scaffold(
            topBar = {
                TopAppBar(
                    title = { Text(text = "My Cart") }
                )
            }
        ) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                LazyColumn(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp)
                ) {
                    item {
                        SeasonalCategoryTitle("Shop By Category")
                    }
                    item {
                        CategoryScreen()
                    }
                    item {
                        SeasonalCategoryTitle("Seasonal Specials")
                    }
                    item {
                        SeasonalCategoryComposable()
                    }
    
                }
            }
        }
    
    }



@Composable
fun CategoryScreen(categoryViewModel: CategoryViewModel = get()) {
    val categoryList: List<Category> = categoryViewModel.categoryList.value

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        categoryViewModel.fetchCategories()
    }
    CategoryGrid(categoryList)

}

@Composable
fun SeasonalCategoryTitle(title: String) {
    DisplayOutLinedLabel(label = title)
}

@Composable
fun SeasonalCategoryComposable(categoryViewModel: CategoryViewModel = get()) {
    val categoryList: List<Category> = categoryViewModel.categoryList.value

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        categoryViewModel.fetchSeasonalCategories()
    }
    SeasonalCategoryRow(categoryList)

}

@Composable
fun SeasonalCategoryRow(categories: List<Category>) {
    LazyRow(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(10.dp)
    ) {
        items(categories.size) { index ->
            SeasonalCategoryItem(category = categories[index])
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun CategoryGrid(categories: List<Category>) {
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
        modifier = Modifier.height(400.dp),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp)
    ) {
        items(categories.size) { index ->
            CategoryItem(category = categories[index])
        }
    }

}

@Composable
fun SeasonalCategoryItem(category: Category) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(2.dp)
            .height(height = 100.dp)
            .width(width = 100.dp)
            .border(
                BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.LightGray)/*,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)*/
            ),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            //  CategoryImage(category.categoryImage)
            //  CategoryImageFromUrl(category.categoryImage)
            CategoryImageFromURLWithPlaceHolder(category.categoryImage)
            CategoryName(category.categoryName)

        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CategoryItem(category: Category) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(100.dp)
            .border(
                BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.LightGray)/*,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)*/
            ),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            //  CategoryImage(category.categoryImage)
            //  CategoryImageFromUrl(category.categoryImage)
            CategoryImageFromURLWithPlaceHolder(category.categoryImage)
            CategoryName(category.categoryName)

        }
    }

}

@Composable
fun CategoryName(categoryName: String) {
    DisplayLabel(categoryName)

}

@Composable
fun CategoryImageFromURLWithPlaceHolder(imageUrl: String) {
    FetchImageFromURLWithPlaceHolder(imageUrl = imageUrl)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach I would use is to place `BoxWithConstraints` then get the value of `maxHeight` devide it as you need and pass it through `modifiers` to your other composables. So you can have a more responsive design depending on different screen sizes.